# Python NLTK: generate() function cannot be used

Tags: python, nltk

I shouldn't be getting this error. This has worked before and any tutorial goes over this in the same way and it works. Please help.

```
import nltk 
from nltk.book import *

text3.generate()
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e0816ba18b61> in <module>()
----> 1 text3.generate()

AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'generate'
```

print sys.version #my python version
2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fourth note in the [first online chapter of the NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#searching-text) book says that:

> The generate() method is not available in NLTK 3.0 but will be
>   reinstated in a subsequent version

Comment: Ahhhh, I do have NLTK 3.0 What steps can I take to use the generate() function?

Comment: Base on your OS follow the installation instruction (http://www.nltk.org/install.html)